# How to set textview to show more than 1 line of database value?

Tags: android, database, textview

I have a edit text which is multi line (which saves more than 1 line of text) indeed I want to show the values of it inserted in my database in the textview. PS: I know is something like this:

```
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

But as I know it only shows one line or something like it, Im kinda new to android programming so therefore if you can simplify your answer it will be better for me to understand.
and I dont know if it can be showed in the textview also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope it works, try it

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:lines="4" />
```